# Unable to pass data to php using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

First i echo images for which i set ID with php function. Now im tyring to get the ID value with jQuery click function and pass it to another php function, but unfortunately i always get the undefined index error. Can the reason be in xampp config or something else? Becasuse the code seems to be "right".

jQuery

```
$(function postImgId() {
    $('img').click(function() {
        var imgId = $(this).attr('id');
        $.post('functions.php', {postId:imgId},
            function(data) {
                $('#content').html(data);
                console.log(imgId);
            });
        }); 
    });
```

php

```
function showPlayer() {
    $number ='';    
    $number = $_POST['postId'];

    if(isset($_POST['postId'])) {
        echo "<h2>";
        echo $_POST['postId'];
        echo "</h2>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Pass parameter to the function.

Comment: Sorry im new to this, can you tell me how?

Comment: Aside from you not actually calling `showPlayer`, and assuming that your images actually have ids, that looks like it should work.

Comment: Images have ID-s, i do call the method but in the view file.

Comment: I suspect you're trying to post this data when a user Clicks on a the image?

Comment: You should not need to post it to PHP, this can all be done in JQuery.

Comment: But i need this ID for sql query. Right now the $_POST variable doesnt get value.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

Put this in your click function:

```
   var imgId = $(this).attr('id'); 
   $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "functions.php",
        data: 'playerId=' + imgId,
        success: function(data){
            $('#content').html(data);
        }
    });
```

now check with `isset($_GET['playerId'])` and so on in your php:

```
    if(isset($_GET['playerId'])) {
        echo "<h2>";
        echo $_GET['playerId'];
        echo "</h2>";
    }
```

This playerId should not be something important in your database like the unique AI id.

Whole thing also works with POST see: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: Still getting undefinex variable playerId :s

Comment: Yes as it get written in console log

Comment: Ok, then you should add more code to your example. Some more php-error output?